# Retrieve references from a paper using doi

Tags: r, scopus

How can we retrieve all  references from a paper using the doi and save them into a dataframe?

Using rscopus:

```
library(rscopus)
library(dplyr)

auth_token_header("please_add")
akey="please_add"
object_retrieval("10.1109/ISCSLP.2014.6936630", ref = "doi")
```

Is this the correct option?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Check the result against the list of references in the paper and you'll see if it is correct.

Comment: @Roland my question is how can I retrieve the references from a paper using the doi?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is actually indexed by Scopus.

```r
library(rscopus)
x = abstract_retrieval("10.1109/ISCSLP.2014.6936630", identifier= "doi")
#> HTTP specified is:https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/doi/10.1109/ISCSLP.2014.6936630
x$content
#> $`service-error`
#> $`service-error`$status
#> $`service-error`$status$statusCode
#> [1] "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"
#> 
#> $`service-error`$status$statusText
#> [1] "The resource specified cannot be found."

process_author_name(last_name = "Lin", first_name = "Xuee")
#> HTTP specified is (without API key): https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/author?query=AUTHFIRST%28Xuee%29%2BAND%2BAUTHLAST%28Lin%29&count=200&start=0
#> Error in process_author_name(last_name = "Lin", first_name = "Xuee"): No author name found
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately I can't run it even if I have the latest version of rscopus I receive this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54403383/scopus-api-wrong

Comment: Please read the documentation from the package on how to get an API key as you do not have one.  I cannot help you any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the correct option. But Scopus discriminates between (academic) subscribers and non-subscribers. Many of the available items are disabled by default for non-subscribers. You can check the available items here: https://dev.elsevier.com/api_key_settings.html

The table on the page says that citations overview is disabled by default, not available to non-subscribers.