# Scopus api wrong

Tags: r

I use this to test if I can retrieve references from a paper using doi from rscopus package

I use this:

```
library(rscopus)
library(dplyr)

auth_token_header("please_add")
akey="please_add"
object_retrieval("10.1109/ISCSLP.2014.6936630", ref = "doi")
```

but I receive this error:

```
Error in get_api_key(api_key, error = api_key_error) : 
  API key not found, please set option('elsevier_api_key_filename') or option('elsevier_api_key') for general use or set environment variable Elsevier_API, to be accessed by Sys.getenv('Elsevier_API')
```

Why do I receive it?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions given in the error message to set your API key?

Comment: @camille unfortunately I can't understand. I typed the command in R studio but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps I outlined in the section of https://github.com/muschellij2/rscopus#steps-to-get-api-key

Which is posted below:

In order to use this package, you need an API key from https://dev.elsevier.com/sc_apis.html.  You should login from your institution and go to Create API Key.  You need to provide a website URL and a label, but the website can be your personal website, and agree to the terms of service.

1. Go to https://dev.elsevier.com/user/login. Login or create a free account.
2. Click "Create API Key".  Put in a label, such as `rscopus key`.  Add a website.  http://example.com is fine if you do not have a site.
3. **Read** and agree to the TOS if you do indeed agree.
4. Add `Elsevier_API = "API KEY GOES HERE"` to `~/.Renviron` file, or add `export Elsevier_API=API KEY GOES HERE` to your `~/.bash_profile`.

Alternatively, you you can either set the API key using `rscopus::set_api_key` or by `options("elsevier_api_key" = api_key)`.  You can access the API key using `rscopus::get_api_key`.

You should be able to test out the API key using the [interactive Scopus APIs](https://dev.elsevier.com/scopus.html).

#### A note about API keys and IP addresses

The API Key is bound to a set of IP addresses, usually bound to your institution.  Therefore, if you are using this for a Shiny application, you must host the Shiny application from your institution servers in some way.  Also, you cannot access the Scopus API with this key if you are offsite and must VPN into the server or use a computing cluster with an institution IP.

See https://dev.elsevier.com/tecdoc_api_authentication.html