# Authorization error in Scopus Search in R (rscopus)

Tags: r

I did a Scopus search using rscopus package with the following code:

```
author_search(au_id = "Smith", 
            searcher = "affil(princeton) and authlast")
```

I got the following error:

Error in get_results(au_id, start = init_start, count = count, facets = facets,  :
Unauthorized (HTTP 401).

However, this code works well:

```
scopus_search(query = "Vocabulary", max_count = 20,
              count = 10)
```

I have set the Scopus API Key using `options("elsevier_api_key" = "MY-API-KEY-HERE")`. So, I wonder what the problem is.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54403383/scopus-api-wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already have API Key.